# Adding records to the database using class function

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm trying to add records to the database using function like this:

```
require_once('../config/Database.php');

class Category {
    private $conn;
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $description;
    private $created;

public function __construct($db) {
    $this->conn = $db;
}

public function addRecord($n, $desc) {
        $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO categories VALUES('', '$n', '$desc', CURDATE())")->execute();
        $this->name = $n;
        $this->description = $desc;
    }
```

and to call it with it:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
if ( isset( $_POST['addRecord'], $_POST['n'], $_POST['desc']) ) {

    $cat = new Category($conn);

    $n = filter_input ( INPUT_POST , 'n', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $desc = filter_input ( INPUT_POST , 'desc', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $cat->addRecord($n, $desc);
    }
}
?>
<div style="border: 5px solid black; width: 40%">
<h3>addRecord($n, $desc):</h3>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Category name :</label>
<input type="text" name="n" id="n" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Name"/><br /><br />
<label>Category description :</label>
<input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Description"/><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="addRecord" name="addRecord"/><br />
</form>
</div>
```

Database connection is here:

```
<?php

class Database {

public function getConnection() {
    $result = false;
    try {
        $result = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demo', 'root', '');
    } catch(PDOException $e) { }
    return $result;
    }
}
$db = new Database();
$conn = $db->getConnection();
if (!$conn) {
    die("Error connecting to the database");
}

?>
```

I'm not getting any error but it's not working, just nothing happends when I press the "addRecord" button

Comment: You can display errors if there by using `error_reporting(E_ALL);  ini_set(display_errors,1);`.

Comment: I got it, there was a problem with the sql query in my code